# java.lang.RuntimeException App Crash from Google Play Console

Tags: java, android, gradle

The below log is copied from Google Play Console Crash log.

My App crashed on Android 4.4 device (Samsung Galaxy Tab E 9.6) and I don't understand what is this exception about. It works good on all other versions, and I cannot reproduce the exception.

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: 
  at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity (ActivityThread.java:2429)
  at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity (ActivityThread.java:2493)
  at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800 (ActivityThread.java:166)
  at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage (ActivityThread.java:1283)
  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage (Handler.java:102)
  at android.os.Looper.loop (Looper.java:136)
  at android.app.ActivityThread.main (ActivityThread.java:5590)
  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative (Native Method)
  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke (Method.java:515)
  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run (ZygoteInit.java:1268)
  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main (ZygoteInit.java:1084)
  at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main (Native Method)
Caused by: android.view.InflateException: 
  at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag (LayoutInflater.java:720)
  at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate (LayoutInflater.java:762)
  at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate (LayoutInflater.java:771)
  at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate (LayoutInflater.java:499)
  at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate (LayoutInflater.java:398)
  at com.jeyom.boxthought.BoxItemFragment.onCreateView (BoxItemFragment.java:58)
  at android.support.v4.app.Fragment.performCreateView (Fragment.java:2346)
  at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState (FragmentManager.java:1428)
  at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveFragmentToExpectedState (FragmentManager.java:1759)
  at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState (FragmentManager.java:1827)
  at android.support.v4.app.BackStackRecord.executeOps (BackStackRecord.java:797)
  at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.executeOps (FragmentManager.java:2596)
  at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.executeOpsTogether (FragmentManager.java:2383)
  at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.removeRedundantOperationsAndExecute (FragmentManager.java:2338)
  at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.execPendingActions (FragmentManager.java:2245)
  at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.dispatchStateChange (FragmentManager.java:3248)
  at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.dispatchActivityCreated (FragmentManager.java:3200)
  at android.support.v4.app.FragmentController.dispatchActivityCreated (FragmentController.java:195)
  at android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity.onStart (FragmentActivity.java:597)
  at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity.onStart (AppCompatActivity.java:177)
  at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnStart (Instrumentation.java:1178)
  at android.app.Activity.performStart (Activity.java:5457)
  at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity (ActivityThread.java:2402)
Caused by: android.content.res.Resources$NotFoundException: 
  at android.content.res.Resources.loadDrawable (Resources.java:3453)
  at android.content.res.TypedArray.getDrawable (TypedArray.java:614)
  at android.widget.TextView.<init> (TextView.java:898)
  at android.widget.Button.<init> (Button.java:107)
  at android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatButton.<init> (AppCompatButton.java:70)
  at android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatButton.<init> (AppCompatButton.java:66)
  at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatViewInflater.createButton (AppCompatViewInflater.java:186)
  at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatViewInflater.createView (AppCompatViewInflater.java:109)
  at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegateImplV9.createView (AppCompatDelegateImplV9.java:1035)
  at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegateImplV9.onCreateView (AppCompatDelegateImplV9.java:1092)
  at android.view.LayoutInflater$FactoryMerger.onCreateView (LayoutInflater.java:173)
  at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag (LayoutInflater.java:691)
Caused by: org.xmlpull.v1.XmlPullParserException: 
  at android.graphics.drawable.Drawable.createFromXmlInner (Drawable.java:969)
  at android.graphics.drawable.Drawable.createFromXml (Drawable.java:913)
  at android.content.res.Resources.loadDrawable (Resources.java:3449)
```

Comment: A `Button` in your `BoxItemFragment` layout refers to a drawable resource that for some reason is not there in that configuration.

Comment: On Android 4.4 that could be an issue with a vector drawable. Post the XML for BoxItemFragment

Answer (score 1):

The error is caused due to layout not getting inflated in Samsung Galaxy Tab E 9.6. screen size.

Please check for layout with different screen size before running it on actual device